# Generating AngularJS UI templates from dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and the front end development and trying to learn Angular and create something with it. I've gone through the basics and more advanced stuff and know my way around and created a few sample apps and now starting to build something useful. 
I have a data model defined on the server side and I want to present them in the front end. Apparently the usual approach is to create the html templates, bind the fields and then glue them all through something like ui-router which works but I'm thinking of building something more dynamic that can present the data without first creating the templates. I'm not sure if this is doable or even a good idea though so that's my question. 
Is there something out there than can build these partial templates based on the data model (my preference is runtime but design time is good as well)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done. Please refer to this link
https://gist.github.com/rohit9889/3918170.

```
// My Application
var myApp = angular.module('myAngularApp', ['ui']);

// A Directive to generate Dynamic Template
myApp.directive('dynamicTemplate', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { form_generator_schema: '=data' },
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
      console.log("Directive Called");
      var schema = scope.form_generator_schema.schema;
      var field_inputs = "";
      for (var field in schema){
        var new_field = "";
        var field_type = schema[field].data_type == "boolean" ? "checkbox" : schema[field].data_type;

        switch (field_type){
          case 'file':
            new_field = "<div>" + schema[field].display_name + ":<input type='file' ng-model='" + field_type + "' id='fileToUpload' class='file-field' /></div>";
            break;
          default:
            new_field = "<div>" + schema[field].display_name + ":<input type='" + field_type + "' ng-model='" + field_type + "'/></div>";
        }

        field_inputs = field_inputs + new_field;
      }
      elm.append($compile(field_inputs)(scope));
    }
  };
});


// My Controller
function myController($scope){
  $scope.dynamicContent = {
    "schema":[
      {"data_type":"string", "display_name":"MyField123"},
      {"data_type":"file", "display_name":"MyField456"},
      {"data_type":"checkbox", "display_name":"MyField789"}
    ]
  };
}
```

Comment: Code shown has XSS vulnerability (what if the display_name is `<script>alert('lmao')</script>`, or worse?). Don't concatenate raw strings into HTML. Prefer creating elements as objects, setting properties, and appending them together as a document fragment. At the very least, escape non-html input strings. You need to replace < with `&lt;` & with `&amp;` " with `&quot;` and ' with `&#39;` (quote escapes are only needed for attribute values).